# SceneKit(ARKit) - Huge lag on adding multiple nodes

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, scenekit, gamekit

In my AR game, at specific intervals, a function is called that adds multiple nodes to the scene (between 1 and 12 nodes). These individual nodes are all the same - they consist of the same blender model, same SCNCone, same spotlight and same physics bodies. **But when I add them performance drops from 60fps to 30 fps**.

**Tride solutions**: cloning nodes and sharing geometries, preparing to render on SCNView, preloading and storing loaded nodes but nothing helps.

Please help me to find a correct solution for best performance!

Some data about objects:

**vertex**: ~5000 per 1 objects

**polygons**: ~1800 per 1 objects

**Bounding Box**: 
width - 60
height - 25
depth - 20

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I have been experiencing the same. I even have a freeze on the demo app from apple when the chameleon is added to the scene on an iPhone 7 Plus.

Comment: I've been experiencing the same issues. My AR app would randomly reduce to 30fps, even when the number of polygons did not change (~6.8K to 10K). Reinstalling the app doesn't even fix it, and randomly it would resume to operate at 60fps. When operating at 30fps, It's telling me that CPU utilization takes 33ms per frame, even though I haven't actually changed anything.

Comment: Hi, do you found how to solve the issue?